# How to implement Polymorphism for Enum?

Tags: java, enums, polymorphism

I have a `enum` called `Status` as following representing the http request status to a service:

```
public enum Status {
    UNKNOWN,
    COMPLETED,
    FAILED,
    CANCELLED;
}
```

where:

- `UNKNOWN` is the initial status;
- `COMPLETED`, `FAILED` and `CANCELLED` are representing three branches of the [FutureCallback](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/concurrent/FutureCallback.html) when you are doing async request using Apache HTTP Client, for example: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/quickstart.html

However, `COMPLETED` does not mean the response code is definitely 200; and `FAILED` does not mean the errored code of response. Instead, responses like 500, 404 will all go to the branch of `COMPLETED`.

Therefore, I would like to to have status `SUCCESS` and `ERROR`. Both of them are `COMPLETED`, but also `Status`. Something similar to the following one (but it is not correct and not allowed by Java):

```
public enum Status {
    UNKNOWN,
    SUCCESS,
    ERROR,
    FAILED,
    CANCELLED;

    public enum COMPLETED extends Status {
        SUCCESS, ERROR;
    }
}
```

Something similar to the Polymorphism of classes:

- `UNKNOWN` **is** `Status`
- `FAILED` **is** `Status`
- `CANCELLED` **is** `Status`
- `COMPLETED` **is** `Status`

  - `SUCCESS` **is** `Status`
  - `SUCCESS` **is** `COMPLETED`
  - `ERROR` **is** `Status`
  - `ERROR` **is** `COMPLETED`

Anyone know how to implement such mechanism?

Comment: Enums can implement interfaces; individual constants can implement methods separately by adding `{ /* class body */ }` after the constant.

Comment: But if Enum implements interface, I cannot do switch on the interface right? @AndyTurner

Comment: Of course you can. If in doubt: try it!

Comment: `enum COMPLETED` can have constructor that accepts `Success` as param and `SUCCESS` in `COMPLETED` can be `SUCCESS(Status.SUCCESS)`

Comment: I cannot do switch on interface, I have tried: "Incompatible types: Found Status, required: char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer, String, or and enum" @AndyTurner

Comment: You can't switch on an interface, but you can switch on an enum; and whether that enum implements an interface is irrelevant to that.